# Cmake: ld cannot open map file Unit_Test.map: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, linker

I'm working on an embedded C project in Eclipse, cross-compiling to an M4 Cortex target. We are using Cmake (version 3.7.x) to recurse through all of the project files and build them accordingly. We have a "Main_App" and "Unit_test". The unit test depends on multiple libraries and source files from "Main_App." When I go to build the "Unit_Test", the linker complains saying that it cannot find "Unit_Test.map".

"Cmake: ld cannot open map file Unit_Test.map: No such file or directory"

My CMakeLists.txt file looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

file(GLOB LD_FILE *gcc_nrf52.ld)

create_application(
    NAME
        "Unit_Test"
PLATFORM
        target
INCLUDE_DIRS
    inc
        ../../../apps/Main_App
        ../../../apps/Main_App/stuff
        ../../../apps/Main_App/more_stuff
LINKER_SCRIPT
    ${LD_FILE}
SOURCES
    main.c
LIBRARIES
    someLib1
    someLib2
    someLib3
)
```

1) Why is there no map file being created?
2) Is my CMakeLists.txt file incorrect?
3) Is there anything else that I'm missing in the "Unit_Test" directory?

Build Console Output:

```
"cd /Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/unit_tests/stimulation_module && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/stim_module_unit_test.elf.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fno-builtin --std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -fshort-enums --specs=nosys.specs -g -O1 -g   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--static -Wl,--cref -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 --specs=nano.specs -lc  -L/Users/sami/dev/Github/CalaTWO-NRF52832/submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/gcc/  -Wl,-T,/Users/sami/dev/Github/CalaTWO-NRF52832/apps/unit_tests/stimulation_module/unit_tests_gcc_nrf52.ld -Xlinker -Map=/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test/stim_module_unit_test.map CMakeFiles/stim_module_unit_test.elf.dir/main.c.obj  -o stim_module_unit_test.elf ../../../CalaDrivers/libCalaDrivers.a ../../../MTKeystone/libMTKeystone.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/timer/libnrf_drv_timer.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/ble/libble.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/sensorsim/libsensorsim.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/rng/libnrf_drv_rng.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/twi_master/libtwi_master.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/spi_master/libspi_master.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/pwm/libnrf_drv_pwm.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fds/libfds.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fstorage/libfstorage.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/trace/libtrace.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/ble_flash/libble_flash.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/pstorage/libpstorage.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/button/libbutton.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/hal/libhal.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/timer/libtimer.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/util/libutil.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/common/libcommon.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/clock/libclock.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/gpiote/libnrf_drv_gpiote.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/delay/libdelay.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/uart/libuart.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fifo/libfifo.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/uart/libnrf_drv_uart.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/button/libbutton.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/hal/libhal.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/timer/libtimer.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/util/libutil.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/common/libcommon.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/clock/libclock.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/gpiote/libnrf_drv_gpiote.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/delay/libdelay.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/uart/libuart.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fifo/libfifo.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/uart/libnrf_drv_uart.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a ../../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a 
**/usr/local/Caskroom/gcc-arm-embedded/5_4-2016q3,20160926/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot open map file /Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test/stim_module_unit_test.map: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
make[2]: *** [apps/unit_tests/stimulation_module/stim_module_unit_test.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/unit_tests/stimulation_module/CMakeFiles/stim_module_unit_test.elf.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 89%] Built target i2s
[ 90%] Linking C executable cala_stim_therapy.elf
cd /Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/cala_stim_therapy && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fno-builtin --std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -fshort-enums --specs=nosys.specs -g -O1 -g   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--static -Wl,--cref -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 --specs=nano.specs -lc  -L/Users/sami/dev/Github/CalaTWO-NRF52832/submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/gcc/  -Wl,-T,/Users/sami/dev/Github/CalaTWO-NRF52832/apps/cala_stim_therapy/cala_stim_therapy_gcc_nrf52.ld -Xlinker -Map=/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/cala_stim_therapy/cala_stim_therapy.map CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/ble/ble_test.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/console/RetargetSerial.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/console/Commands.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/resources/glyphs.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/resources/GlyphsLibrary.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/TopStateMachine.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/Power.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/UserInterface.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/Band.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/Stim.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/modules/SystemMonitor.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/pharmacy/Pharmacy.c.obj CMakeFiles/cala_stim_therapy.elf.dir/main.c.obj  -o cala_stim_therapy.elf ../../CalaDrivers/libCalaDrivers.a ../../MTKeystone/libMTKeystone.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/timer/libnrf_drv_timer.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/ble/libble.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/sensorsim/libsensorsim.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/rng/libnrf_drv_rng.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/twi_master/libtwi_master.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/spi_master/libspi_master.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/pwm/libnrf_drv_pwm.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fds/libfds.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fstorage/libfstorage.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/trace/libtrace.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/ble_flash/libble_flash.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/pstorage/libpstorage.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/button/libbutton.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/hal/libhal.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/timer/libtimer.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/util/libutil.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/common/libcommon.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/clock/libclock.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/gpiote/libnrf_drv_gpiote.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/delay/libdelay.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/uart/libuart.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fifo/libfifo.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/uart/libnrf_drv_uart.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/bsp/libbsp.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/scheduler/libscheduler.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/softdevice/libsoftdevice.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/button/libbutton.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/hal/libhal.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/timer/libtimer.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/util/libutil.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/common/libcommon.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/clock/libclock.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/gpiote/libnrf_drv_gpiote.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/delay/libdelay.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/uart/libuart.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/libraries/fifo/libfifo.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/drivers_nrf/uart/libnrf_drv_uart.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a ../../submodules/nrf52_sdk/components/toolchain/libtoolchain.a 
[ 91%] Built target led_softblink
[ 97%] Built target cala_stim_therapy.elf
make: *** [all] Error 2 "
```

Comment: It's not saying it can't find `Unit_Test.map`. It wants to *write*
the map file and apparently can't because the directory in which it is
being told to write it doesn't exist. To get an explanation of what
it wrong with the linkage command you'll need to show us the
linkage command and the output that follows from it, which you'll get by running `make VERBOSE=`
instead of `make`. The made-up `CMakeLists.txt` by itself is not useful.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, I will post the build console output for further analysis. I'm not sure where Cmake wants me to explicitly state where the .map and .hex files need to go. Within this build, a main_app and a ble_app are successfully created and I couldn't find where the command exists to write their respective .map and .hex files.

Comment: Typo in previous comment: should be `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: What is the output of the command `ls /Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test`

Comment: @MikeKinghan The output of **/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/unit_tests** is: "CMakeFiles", "Makefile", "cmake_install.cmake", and "stimulation_module". An 'ls' of "stimulation_module" yields: "CMakeFiles", "Makefile", and "cmake_install.cmake".

Comment: You haven't done that right. It cannot be the case that the directory listing of `/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test`
is `/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_file‌​s/apps/unit_tests`.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, after you posed the question, I realized that the name of my application "stim_module_unit_test" must match the directory. I was able to solve the problem with your help. Thank you. My application now builds a .map file and a .hex file accordingly.

Comment: Yes. Your linkage option `-Map=/Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test/stim_module_unit_test.map` asks for the map file to be written in `Users/sami/dev/Github/target_debug_eclipse_files/apps/stim_module_unit_test/`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add `\" \"`. CMake does not autoamtically add `"` to your path. If your path (in my case) contains any spaces, you'll need to add an escape sequence with `"` accordingly. That is for e.g.

```
"${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=\"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map\""
```